# Chinese character encoding error with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'd like to use BeatifulSoup to get the data in a table from a website, but it couldn't grab the Chinese character correctly.
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.515fa.com/che_1978.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,from_encoding="UTF-8")
print soup.prettify()
```

And the Chinese characters are displayed like this:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" u1:str="" width="173">
               ćé¸</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" u1:str="" width="149">
               ä¸ćľˇĺ¤§äź</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" u1:str="" width="126">
               ĺ¤§äź</td>
```

I really don't know what the "ä¸ćľˇĺ¤§äź" is. I tried to change the encoding "utf-8" to "gb18030", but it didn't work. 
How can I get the correct Chinese characters? Thanks!

Comment: What are you outputting this HTML *to*? The browser? The console?

Comment: @deceze the Terminal.app on MacBook.

Comment: What's the encoding used by the terminal output? You may need to do something like `print soup.prettify().encode('gb18030')` or something like that.

Comment: Is your terminal configured to use UTF-8? Or is it using gb18030? The page has a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` line. I don't have any fonts that are adequate to display Chinese properly in my terminal, but that page _does_ appear to be UTF-8 encoded. (FWIW, there's no encoding info supplied in the page's headers, and the Requests module _guesses_ the encoding to be ISO-8859-1, but that's not unusual.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.515fa.com/che_1978.html")
content = html.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Not sure what exactly `BeautifulSoup(from_encoding=)` did but this did the trick.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you very much! I've been working on this for 4 hours! :-)