# BeautifulSoup chinese character encoding error

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to identify and save all of the headlines on a specific site, and keep getting what I believe to be encoding errors.

The site is: http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2016-05/06/nw.D110000renmrb_20160506_2-01.htm

the current code is:

```
holder = {}  

url = urllib.urlopen('http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2016-05/06/nw.D110000renmrb_20160506_2-01.htm').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

head1 = soup.find_all(['h1','h2','h3'])

print head1

holder["key"] = head1
```

The output of the print is:

```
[<h3>\u73af\u5883\u6c61\u67d3\u6700\u5c0f\u5316 \u8d44\u6e90\u5229\u7528\u6700\u5927\u5316</h3>, <h1>\u5929\u6d25\u6ee8\u6d77\u65b0\u533a\uff1a\u697c\u5728\u666f\u4e2d \u5382\u5728\u7eff\u4e2d</h1>, <h2></h2>]
```

I'm reasonably certain that those are unicode characters, but I haven't been able to figure out how to convince python to display them as the characters.

I have tried to find the answer elsewhere.  The question that was more clearly on point was this one:
[Python and BeautifulSoup encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219361/python-and-beautifulsoup-encoding-issues)

which suggested adding

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
```

however that gave me the same error that is mentioned in a comment ("AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'")
removing the second '.BeautifulSoup' resulted in a different error ("RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object").

I also tried the answer suggested here:
[Chinese character encoding error with BeautifulSoup in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176558/chinese-character-encoding-error-with-beautifulsoup-in-python)

by breaking up the creation of the object

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.515fa.com/che_1978.html")
content = html.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

but that also generated the recursion error.  Any other tips would be most appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and tried this one, it works: :https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354890/20294353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decode using [`unicode-escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
In [6]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [7]: h = """<h3>\u73af\u5883\u6c61\u67d3\u6700\u5c0f\u5316 \u8d44\u6e90\u5229\u7528\u6700\u5927\u5316</h3>, <h1>\u5929\u6d25\u6ee8\u6d77\u65b0\u533a\uff1a\u697c\u5728\u666f\u4e2d \u5382\u5728\u7eff\u4e2d</h1>, <h2></h2>"""

In [8]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'lxml')

In [9]: print(soup.h3.text.decode("unicode-escape"))
环境污染最小化 资源利用最大化
```

If you look at the source you can see the data is *utf-8* encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="utf-8" />
```

For me using  *bs4 4.4.1* just decoding what urllib returns works fine also:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: import urllib

In [3]: url = urllib.urlopen('http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2016-05/06/nw.D110000renmrb_20160506_2-01.htm').read()

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(url.decode("utf-8"), 'lxml')

In [5]: print(soup.h3.text)
环境污染最小化 资源利用最大化
```

When you are writing to a csv you will want to *encode* the data to a *utf-8 str*:

```
 .decode("unicode-escape").encode("utf-8")
```

You can do the encode when you save the data in your dict.

Comment: Oh man this is so close!  This works to print the text, which gives me hope that that data is correct.  However, when I tried to add it to the dictionary it reverted back to the unicode.  I broke up step 9 a bit so `g = soup.h3.text.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")` and then `print(g)`.  That worked fine.  But when I tried to add g to the dictionary called holder: `holder["key"] = g` and then `print holder` I got the unicode output again.  Eventually I want to output the dictionary to CSV, and I want to make sure it is right through the chain.

Comment: @user5356756, that is just the repr representation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python, try printing the values themselves from the dict and you should see the same. Also as per the end of the answer, you should really upgrade to bs4

Comment: gotcha, thank you!  That works.  I'm running into trouble transferring the dictionary to a csv using dictwriter, but that's well beyond the scope of this question so I'll do some research and open a new one if need be.  As for bs4, the first line of my script (which I didn't reproduce above) is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.  Is there something beyond that that I need to do in order to switch from 3 to 4?

Comment: ah ok, so you are using bs4, I was unsure when I saw `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup` , out of interest if you `print(bs4.__version__)` what do you see?

Comment: I added that line to the bottom of my script and got the following error: `NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined`

Comment: You need to import bs4. Also to write to a file you should `.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: sorry - 4.4.1.  Is it safe to assume that the `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-14: ordinal not in range(128)` I get when I try and write the dict to a CSV with dictwriter is flowing from this same issue?

Comment: You should actually just need `.decode("unicode-escape").encode("utf-8")`  each unicode string to write to the csv

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand.  if this is the csv code, where does the .decode... go?  `with open('rrs_csv.csv', 'wb') as f:
 w = csv.DictWriter(f, holder.keys())
 w.writeheader()
 w.writerow(holder)`

Comment: When you create the dict, replace the earlier logic with  `h3.text.decode("unicode-escape").encode("utf-8")` etc... when you store the values and your will have no problem writing with the csv lib. We don't  need the initial encode, I should have written it in reverse

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU ARE THE KING OF PYTHON THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

This may provide a pretty simple solution, not sure if it does absolutely everything you need it to though, let me know:

```
holder = {}  

url = urllib.urlopen('http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2016-05/06/nw.D110000renmrb_20160506_2-01.htm').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

head1 = soup.find_all(['h1','h2','h3'])

print unicode(head1)

holder["key"] = head1
```

Reference: [Python 2.7 Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, that gave me the exact same output as before so I've still got u1234 instead of characters.